# Img tag sizing in percentages

Tags: html, css, image, size, height

I've been trying to find an answer online so I didn't have to post, but I can't find a solution!
I'm using a carousel from bootstrap, and my images won't fit. I put the carousel inside a div named "slide". I set width and height on slide, and put a background color to make it easier to see. When I set width in percentage a on my img it resizes to take up the whole width of it's parent container. But when I set height on the img, it makes the image huge!! I want to stretch the image to fit, I don't care about keeping the original ratio. Also if I set the height in pixels or vh it has an affect, the only thing that doesn't work is percentages.
Guys, what am I missing here?

[Width 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZByO.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWDSo.png)

[Height 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3zRG.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwMfS.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. We need to look at your code. Will the layout of this slider help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674446/scale-custom-animation-with-owl-carousel-2/66676219#66676219

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .slide {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #000;
    }
    .slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain; /* When you use Contain proparty you can see full image with black background*/
        object-fit: cover; /* When you use cover proparty you can see it's cover a box as per main div width */
    }
```

```html
<!-- Here I use Display flex instant of float right -->
<div class="slide">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
</div>
```

My suggestion is You can use cover CSS.

Comment: I tried object-fit already and that doesn't help. It's just weird.

Comment: can you please share live code so I can check properly